# Loop insert with select

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert

I have the following structures

**Tickets**

```
+----+---------------------+-----------+---------------+
| id | price               | seat_id   |    flight_id  |
+----+---------------------+-----------+---------------+
```

**Seats**

```
+----+--------+-----------+
| id | letter |  number   |
+----+--------+-----------+
| 1  | A      |     1     |
| 2  | A      |     2     |
| 3  | A      |     3     |
+----+--------+-----------+
```

I want to insert 2 tickets using only one query where the letter is A and the number is between 1 and 2, I guess to make more than 1 insert at time I have to use some plsql loop but I don't know how to do it and i don't know if this is the approach

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are actually wanting to do, but from your description I'll assume you want 2rows in tickets referencing id 1 and 2 from seats.  
SQL works in sets NOT in individual rows and loop (yes those are available via plpgsql) but avoid loops when ever possible. Inserting 2 rows does not require one; in fact it is almost exactly the same as inserting a single row. Since you didn not specify values for price and flight, I'll just omit them. But to insert 2 rows:

```
Insert into tickets(id,seat_id) values (1,1),(2,2);
```

Comment: 2 tickets was just an example, i really want X tickets, why should I avoid using loops?

Comment: Then take a look at [ask]. This will describe what a question requires to get a satisfactory. In this case you specifically ask 2 rows, with no indication of anything else. You need to be specific with your description, your sample data can be reduced. Loops are basically the anti-thesis of SQL. They are also the slowest possible method and then to be more complicated process. Actually loops do not exist in SQL. PLpgsql (Postgres), plsql (Oracle), T-SQL (Sequel Server) are 3rd generation language which integrate SQL.